# What biblatex entry type and fields for downloadable pdf in series?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

What form should a `biblatex` entry take for something like an item in the *AMS Open Math Notes* series? The item is an online, downloadable pdf. Right now I'm trying:

```
  @online{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017,
  author = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
  series = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  year = {2017},
  url = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate = {2017-01-10},
  keywords = {main},
}
```

However, the `series` field is being ignored when I cite this reference.

**Added: bibliography style being used**

In case it helps, I'm using `biblatex`'s `standard` and `numeric` bibliography styles, as modified in a `biblatex.cfg` file that includes the following —  so as to imitate the `amsplain` style.

```
% BIBLATEX.CFG - mimic amsplain
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}
%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

% Punctuation & delimiter mods:
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings} % external file!
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Field mods:
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field

% URL mods:
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% Book mods:    
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

Comment: `@book` might be appropriate.

Comment: I though of `@book` originally, but I wonder if that's appropriate given that the items in the series in question are explicitly designated as "works in progress" and/or course notes. And will `@book` allow a `url` field? (There's the additional issue that these items, as works in progress, have specific dates - year, month, day.)

Comment: You can go for `@booklet` if you feel that conveys the fickleness of the matter enough. A `@booklet` does not have explicit `publisher`, though, only `howpublished`, so `@book` might be nicer after all. Full dates are available with the `date` field instead of `year`: `date = {2017-01-11}`.

Comment: `@booklet` does not show the `series` in the bibliography listing. I guess `@book` for now. Perhaps Barbara Beeton will see this and indicate what the preferred reference form might be for this series.

Comment: The modifications you apply make the difference between the entry types in output even smaller than they already are. So in a way it is even less important which style you pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you exactly think your bibliography should do. It also depends on your specific bibliography style. Entry types are not always clear cut. In some styles the different entry types have more distinct output and in other styles the differences are minute.

From what I can see,

```
@online{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017,
  author   = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title    = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  date     = {2017-01-11},
  url      = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate  = {2017-01-10},
  keywords = {main},
}
```

alone would be enough for anyone to locate the source without much work.

If you want to include the *AMS Open Math Notes* series info you can also 'upgrade' the work to `@book`.
It might not be a 'book' in the traditional sense of the word, but I don't think you have to worry about (incorrectly) giving legitimacy to the work by listing it as a `@book` in your database.

```
@book{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017,
  author    = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title     = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
  series    = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  date      = {2017-01-11},
  url       = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate   = {2017-01-10},
  keywords  = {main},
}
```

`@booklet` might give the feel of something more fickle, but neither `series` nor `publisher` are available, we can replace them by `type` and `howpublished`

```
@booklet{TaylorAnalysisOneVar20171,
  author       = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title        = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  date         = {2017-01-11},
  url          = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate      = {2017-01-10},
  type         = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  howpublished = {American Mathematical Society},
  keywords     = {main},
}
```

It is always possible to cobble something together with `addendum`, `howpublished` and `note` that most types and styles support.

Answer (score 2):

To compare the possibilities you have try the following MWE.  Please see that I changed your `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` to `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` and added `type` and `howpublished` to your the `booklet` bib entry.

With the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017,
  author    = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title     = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
  series    = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  date      = {2017},
  url       = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate   = {2017-01-10},
  keywords  = {main},
}
@book{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017a,
  author    = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title     = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  publisher = {American Mathematical Society},
  series    = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  date      = {2017},
  url       = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate   = {2017-01-10},
  keywords  = {main},
}
@booklet{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017b,
  author       = {Taylor, Michael E.},
  title        = {Introduction to Analysis in One Variable},
  publisher    = {American Mathematical Society},
  series       = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  date         = {2017},
  url          = {https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110664},
  urldate      = {2017-01-10},
  type         = {AMS Open Math Notes},
  howpublished = {American Mathematical Society},
  keywords     = {main},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} % <=============================

% Punctuation & delimiter mods:
%\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings} % external file!
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Field mods:
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field

% URL mods:
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% Book mods:    
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\begin{document}
\title{A test paper}
\date{}
\maketitle

This is a sentence quoting \texttt{\@online} \cite{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017}. 
This is a sentence quoting \texttt{\@book} \cite{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017a}. 
This is a sentence quoting \texttt{\@booklet} \cite{TaylorAnalysisOneVar2017b} 
with \texttt{type} and \texttt{howpublished}. 
%\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

you can directly compare the three possibilites (or just add more if you want):

[image: resulting pdf]